# in_app_purchase purchaseID does not stay the same

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I am using the package in_app_purchase. I noticed that the `PurchaseDetails.purchaseID` for past purchases changes because they take the transactionIdentifier instead of checking for a origional transaction. When a transaction is restored the id changes.

[Apple In-app purchase transaction_id of one purchase changes sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312927/apple-in-app-purchase-transaction-id-of-one-purchase-changes-sometimes)

Is anyone else having the same problem?

This is their code to instantiate product details from a transaction

```
  PurchaseDetails.fromSKTransaction(
      SKPaymentTransactionWrapper transaction, String base64EncodedReceipt)
      : this.purchaseID = transaction.transactionIdentifier,
        this.productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier,
        this.verificationData = PurchaseVerificationData(
            localVerificationData: base64EncodedReceipt,
            serverVerificationData: base64EncodedReceipt,
            source: IAPSource.AppStore),
        this.transactionDate = transaction.transactionTimeStamp != null
            ? (transaction.transactionTimeStamp * 1000).toInt().toString()
            : null,
        this.skPaymentTransaction = transaction,
        this.billingClientPurchase = null,
        _platform = _kPlatformIOS {
    status = SKTransactionStatusConverter()
        .toPurchaseStatus(transaction.transactionState);
    if (status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
      error = IAPError(
        source: IAPSource.AppStore,
        code: kPurchaseErrorCode,
        message: transaction.error.domain,
        details: transaction.error.userInfo,
      );
    }
  }
```

Where

```
 this.purchaseID = transaction.transactionIdentifier,
```

Should check if restored and if so take the identifier from the origional transaction.

I'm on the latest version `in_app_purchase: ^0.3.4+16` and flutter `1.20.3 stable channel`

Everytime when I restart my app and call _connection.queryPastPurchases the purchaseID is different of the purchase found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the origional transaction id seems to work great